# Какие запросы отправляет модуль requests питона?

Tags: python, http, requests, post, get

Собственно, в названии вопроса кроется сам вопрос. Стоит задача - отправить сырой HTТР запрос, вручную собранным GET/ POST. Сам модуль requests отправляет запросы как надо. А вот при попытке сделать тоже самое вручную, например, через модули socket, вызывает трудности.
Задумка проста - подсмотреть, что отправляет requests, и повторить. Но как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw

Comment: Конкретнее, см. вот этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816211/4752653

Comment: можете объяснить логику поиска ответа? вы сталкивались ранее с этим вопросом? или использовали определенный гугул вопрос? интересно понять, как вы нашли ответ

Comment: Ну, секрет прост: искать в поисковике на английском. Я обычно ищу на русском, потом, если ничего внятного не находится - ищу на английском. Или сразу ищу на английском, если заранее понимаю, что по нужной мне теме мало материала на русском.